# Protractor: Testing ui-bootstrap tooltip on IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Protractor to test that a tooltip (using ui-bootstrap directive) shows up, I found out that if there is a delay to show up the tooltip then IE gets stuck when the mouse is moved on the element that should trigger the tooltip.

**HTML**

```
<div id="trigger" tooltip-popup-delay="500" tooltip="Tooltip content...">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**JS test code**

```
browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('trigger'))).perform()
  .then(function (){
    browser.sleep('500');
    expect(element(by.id('trigger')).element(by.css('.tooltip')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Removing the tooltip-popup-delay attribute makes the test pass and if I'm right right it's because IE WebDriver achieves hovering "by continuously firing mouse over events at the last location the mouse cursor has been moved to" (see enablePersistentHover option explanation [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)) and then protractor is waiting forever as each mouseover triggers a $timeout.

Every works fine testing on Chrome/Firefox.

My question then is:
Is there a way to do a proper hovering using protractor/IE WebDriver that could make this test pass even with a tooltip that have a delay to show up ?

Answer (score 1):

It would still be a guess, but try *scrolling into view* of the element:

```
var elm = element(by.id('trigger'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());

browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();
```

Note that, as a workaround, you can remove the `tooltip-popup-delay` attribute on the fly:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('tooltip-popup-delay');", elm.getWebElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately suggested by @alecxe not worked for me.
After a few hours I tried to resolve the problem only by using manual triggering of the mouse hover event, but it's actually not that easy as looks.
I've wrote something like:

```
browser.executeScript("
  var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
  event.initMouseEvent('mouseover',true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
  arguments[0].dispatchEvent(event);", elm.getWebElement()
)
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(elm), tooltipDelay);
browser.actions().mouseMove(elm, {x:5, y:5}).perform()
```

First part triggers IE event for hover, after it protractor waits until element will be present and after triggers normal protractor hover - otherwise it can be a problem, that tooltip will never dissappear.
Offset 5px I've used to place the cursor in the middle of element, not sure if it'll be needed for other cases.

That's not a solution, but possibly someone can use it as a source of motivation during the fight with IE.